# Tikz: draw edge from node to label of another edge

Tags: latex, tikz, graph-drawing

I'm trying to figure out how to draw an edge between a node in tikz and the label of an edge between two other nodes. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here's my code:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, top=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}
\newcommand{\assign}{:=}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,auto]
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum size=1.5cm]

    \node[state] (A1) {$A_1$};
    \node[state,above of=A1] (B1) {$B_1$};
    \node[state,above of=B1] (C1) {$C_1$};

    \node[state,right of=A1] (A2) {$A_2$};
    \node[state,above of=A2] (B2) {$B_2$};
    \node[state,above of=B2] (C2) {$C_2$};



    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (A1) edge node {$l_A$} (B2)
    (B1) edge node {$l_B$} (B2)

    ;

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Model}
  \label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Can someone tell me how I can get this effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> You may also add the option `name=<name>` to the `option` list; it has the same effect [as providing a node name with `(name)`]

With your example, this gives:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, top=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}
\newcommand{\assign}{:=}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,auto]
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum size=1.5cm]

    \node[state] (A1) {$A_1$};
    \node[state,above of=A1] (B1) {$B_1$};
    \node[state,above of=B1] (C1) {$C_1$};

    \node[state,right of=A1] (A2) {$A_2$};
    \node[state,above of=A2] (B2) {$B_2$};
    \node[state,above of=B2] (C2) {$C_2$};



    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (A1) edge node[name=la] {$l_A$} (B2)
    (B1) edge node[name=lb] {$l_B$} (B2)

    ;
    \draw[->, thick, bend left=15]  (C1) edge (la) edge (lb); 

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Model}
  \label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muJoC.png)

Answer (score 2):

[This TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29621/how-can-i-express-half-the-distance-between-two-nodes/29624#29624) shows how to apply to your case a `path` from a `node` to the midpoint of two ther `node`s:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,auto]%,on grid
\tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum size=1.5cm]

\node[state] (A1) {$A_1$};
\node[state,above of=A1] (B1) {$B_1$};
\node[state,above of=B1] (C1) {$C_1$};

\node[state,right of=A1] (A2) {$A_2$};
\node[state,above of=A2] (B2) {$B_2$};
\node[state,above of=B2] (C2) {$C_2$};

\path [->,draw,thick] (C1) -- ($ (B1) !.5! (B2) $);
\path [->,draw,thick] (C1) -- ($ (A1) !.5! (B2) $);

\path[->,draw,thick]
  (A1) edge node[near start] {$l_A$} (B2)
  (B1) edge node[near end] {$l_B$} (B2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

This is only a rough starting point: please post a comment saying if this sketch fits or if you'd like some further development.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have additional modifiers on the labels such as `near end` or on the edge like `bend left`. This means that the calc based midpoint solution doesn't always point to the right place. Additionally, I'm trying to show that C1 influences lA and lB, which then influence B1->B2. So I'm really looking for a way to somehow get access to the node that corresponds to the labels. Is there a way to set a variable to one of the labels?  I would like something similar to `(A1) edge node [near start] (lA) {$l_A$} (B2)` so that I can then just do `(C1) edge (lA)` (that doesn't work though)

Answer (score 2):

Answering for those who might be stuck with it also.

You need to create auxiliary coordinates and draw a line to them
(I'm using xetex)

```
% Preamble
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% Preamble end
...
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,auto]%,on grid
\tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum size=1.5cm]

  \node[state] (A1) {$A_1$};
  \node[state,above of=A1] (B1) {$B_1$};
  \node[state,above of=B1] (C1) {$C_1$};

  \node[state,right of=A1] (A2) {$A_2$};
  \node[state,above of=A2] (B2) {$B_2$};
  \node[state,above of=B2] (C2) {$C_2$};

  % Add Aux points
  \coordinate[yshift=0.6cm, right=1cm of B1.east] (aux1);
  \coordinate[yshift=1.6cm, right=0.1cm of A1.east] (aux2);

  % Your desired arrows
  \draw [arrow] (C1.east) to (aux1); % or (C1.east) -- (aux1) if you need multiple operations further
  % Below are three examples of a relatively same result
  \draw [arrow] (C1.south east) .. controls (1.4,3.5) .. (aux2);  
  % \draw [arrow] (C1.south east) to [bend left=24] (aux2);
  % \draw [arrow] (C1.south east) -| ([shift={(0.5cm,0cm)}]C1.south east) -- (aux2); % pointy arrow

  \path[->,draw,thick]
    (A1) edge node[near start] {$l_A$} (B2)
    (B1) edge node[near end] {$l_B$} (B2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]